# Speak or spoke?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, tense

One guy said:

1. The language I speak before learning English was unique.

It sounded unnatural because the verb "speak" in these sentence. I changed it to a few variations.

2. The language I spoke(used to speak) before learning English was unique.( It sounds like he don't speak those languages anymore)
3. The language I speak that I spoke before learning English was unique.( It actually describes the ideal meaning but souns unnatural)

Is 1 correct? If not, are my variations correct(if not, what are the possible variations) and what grammar is this?

Comment: Aren't all languages 'unique:?

Comment: He speaks a language which  is  more unique.  a joke

Comment: that is not important lol i just used it as an adjective.

Comment: but languages can be unique for example there is an language that is spoken by whistling.

Comment: Is the language before English also his *primary* language or his *native* language? It may be easiest to ignore all mention of English and just say "My primary language is unique," or "My native language is unique."

Answer (score 1):

Out of all your variations the possible options are.

> **The language I spoke before learning English was unique**.
>
> **The language I used to speak before learning English was unique**.

The other forms can not be used because  **speak**  refers to  the present time*

Comment: i think Using past simple or used to makes it seem like the language is now not spoken.

Comment: @lollel123.That is what you mean.Now  you are speaking English.

Comment: No. You can speak other languages even though you speak English more often.

Comment: @lollel123.The unique language you spoke was in the past.

Comment: No I want to say that I still speak that unique language in the present.

Comment: @lollel123.Please see my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The form suggested in another answer:

> The language I have been speaking even before learning English is Unique

is not correct. That should be

> The language [that] I was speaking before learning English is unique.

if "unique" is meant to describe that other language. However, if "Unique" the the **name** of an (imaginary) laguage, one might say:

> The language [that] I was speaking before learning English was Unique.

compare

> The language [that] I was speaking before learning English was Russian.

In the original question the form "The language I speak before learning English" is incorrect because "speak" is in the present tense, but "before" indicates a past event, so "spoke" is needed. This is  because one may not use a simple present tense to describe a past action, and this describes the language that was spoken at a past time. The latter verb "was" must agree. This construction can be ambiguous, and additional context must clarify that: "The language I spoke before learning English was Greek. Now I speak both languages." or "The only language i spoke before learning English was Greek."

Comment: I think it is correct. Why is it not correct? And using "was" make it seem like I don't speak it anymore.

Comment: @lollel123 It is incorrect because you may not use a simple present tense to describe a past action, and this describes the language that was spoken at a past time. The latter verb "was" must agree. This can be ambiguous, and additional context must clarify that: "The language I spoke before learning English was Greek. Now I speak both languages." or "The only language i spoke before learning English was Greek."

Comment: But Present Perfect Simple refers to the past.

Comment: Present Perfect Continious is used to say what you have been doing till now so I think it is correct. So can you tell my why is it not correct more clearly?

Comment: If i say "The language I have been speaking since the day I was born before learning English is Russian. Is it correct? I think if I use past perfect continious, it would sound like I stopped speaking Russian. Correct?

Answer (score -1):

> The language I speak before learning English was unique.
>   It sounded unnatural because the verb "speak" in these sentence. I changed it to a few variations.

---

It can be assumed that the person (let's call him Mr One Guy) is still learning English. The sentence makes no sense as it stands no matter how you rearrange the tense etc. It has no context and is not a logical statement.

However it could mean **The language Mr One Guy learnt to speak before he studied English was unique**. or **Mr One Guy's native language is unique** which I think is the most likely.

Either way the answer to the question;

> Is 1 (the original statement) correct? If not, are my variations correct(if not, what are the possible variations) and what grammar is this?

**The original is incorrect** grammar and all variations are merely speculation **any answer has to be opinion based** and has no value because the owner of the statement is not the person who posted the question so any answer cannot be verified.

Comment: Lets assume that he is referring to his native language. I think present simple is wrong in these sentence

Comment: It is not just one word that is incorrect, as you have pointed out the meaning is unclear, You or anyone else cannot make a silk purse out of a pigs ear. Why analysis something that you can have no definite answer to? The original statement is a mess and without interrogation of the owner anything and everything is speculation.